# Adding an index to an RDD using a shared mutable state

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Take this simple RDD as an example for explaining the problem:

```
val testRDD=sc.parallelize(List((1, 2), (3, 4), (3, 6)))
```

I have this function to help me implement the indexing:

```
 var sum = 0; 

 def inc(l: Int): Int = {
    sum += l
    sum 
 }
```

Now I want to create the id for each tuple:

```
val indexedRDD= testRDD.map(x=>(x._1,x._2,inc(1)));
```

The output RDD should be  `((1,2,1), (3,4,2), (3,6,3))`

But it turned out that all the values are same. It is taking 1 for all the tuples:

```
((1,2,1), (3,4,1), (3,6,1))
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there any other way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
def zipWithIndex(): RDD[(T, Long)]
```

However, note from the docs:

> Note that some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not
>   guarantee order of elements in a partition. The index assigned to each
>   element is therefore not guaranteed, and may even change if the RDD is
>   reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee the same
>   index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it
>   to a file.

Comment: cool...thanks.This one working! but that only answers one part of my question. any idea about why function is not working ?

Comment: I have another RDD created from a file with tab separated fields..call it clickRDD . In this case its working fine..val pairs = clickRDD.map(x => (x.split("\t")(0), inc(1))) ..why is it not working with earlier case..in both the cases, i used map function and both are RDDs.

Comment: Spark runs `map` in parallel. Each parallel task has it's own view of `sum`. They can be running on different JVMs or over over different machines. As a rule of thumb, you should never access mutable state within a closure in Spark.